# Javascript: get Monday and Sunday of the previous week

Tags: javascript

I am using the following script to get Monday (first) and Sunday (last) for the previous week:

```
var curr = new Date; // get current date
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() - 6; // Gets day of the month (e.g. 21) - the day of the week (e.g. wednesday = 3) = Sunday (18th) - 6
var last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6
var startDate = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
var endDate = new Date(curr.setDate(last));
```

This works fine if last Monday and Sunday were also in the same month, but I just noticed today that it doesn't work if today is December and last Monday was in November.

I'm a total JS novice, is there another way to get these dates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you dont want to do it with an external library you should work with timestamps. i created a solution where you would substract 60*60*24*7*1000 (which is 604800000, which is 1 week in milliseconds) from the current Date and go from there:

```
var beforeOneWeek = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 1000)
  , day = beforeOneWeek.getDay()
  , diffToMonday = beforeOneWeek.getDate() - day + (day === 0 ? -6 : 1)
  , lastMonday = new Date(beforeOneWeek.setDate(diffToMonday))
  , lastSunday = new Date(beforeOneWeek.setDate(diffToMonday + 6));
```

Comment: Does not work in countries that use DST, because one week is not always 60*60*24*7*1000ms. For example at 2014-03-31 00:30:00 in France, lastMonday would be 2014-03-17 even though March 24th and March 31st are Mondays.

Answer (score 31):

You can get the previous Monday by getting the Monday of this week and subtracting 7 days. The Sunday will be one day before that, so:

```
var d = new Date();

// set to Monday of this week
d.setDate(d.getDate() - (d.getDay() + 6) % 7);

// set to previous Monday
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);

// create new date of day before
var sunday = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate() - 1);
```

For 2012-12-03 I get:

```
Mon 26 Nov 2012
Sun 25 Nov 2012
```

Is that what you want?

```
// Or new date for the following Sunday
var sunday = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate() + 6);
```

which gives

```
Sun 02 Dec 2012
```

In general, you can manipulate date objects by add and subtracting years, months and days. The object will handle negative values automatically, e.g.

```
var d = new Date(2012,11,0)
```

Will create a date for 2012-11-30 (noting that months are zero based so 11 is December). Also:

```
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1); // 2012-10-30

d.setDate(d.getDate() - 30);  // 2012-09-30
```

Comment: Thanks Rob - this looks good - the dates I would need would be Mon 26 nov 2012 and Sun 2 December 2012.

Comment: Ok, so instead of subtracting 1 day for the Sunday, add 6.

Comment: Good one. Start with good logic, then finish with simple code. Impressive...

Answer (score 4):

You could use a library like moment.js.
See the `subtract` method http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/

Comment: can you explain how, other than just linking to moment?

Comment: moment().day(-6) to get last monday and moment().day(-1) to get last sunday (where monday is the first day of the week and sunday is the last otherwise moment().day(-7) to get last sunday)

Answer (score 3):

A few answers mentioned moment, but no one wrote about this simple method:

```
moment().day(-13) // Monday last week
moment().day(-7) // Sunday last week
```

`.day` sets a week day, so it doesn't matter what day is it today, only week matters.

Comment: So if i run -7 on a monday, then on a tuesday.. wont i end up with two different days?

Comment: @Mayhem no, it will always be Sunday, unless it's locale dependant, I don't quite remember. But it definitely doesn't depend on current date, you can test it yourself.

Comment: This is so much easier, love it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the general solution of find any day of any week.

```
function getParticularDayTimestamp(lastWeekDay) {
  var currentWeekMonday = new Date().getDate() - new Date().getDay() + 1;
  return new Date().setDate(currentWeekMonday - lastWeekDay);
}

console.log(getParticularDayTimestamp(7)) // for last week monday
console.log(getParticularDayTimestamp(1)) // for last week sunday
console.log(getParticularDayTimestamp(14)) // for last to last week monday
console.log(getParticularDayTimestamp(8)) // for last to last week sunday
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Moment you can do the following

```
  var lastWeek          = moment().isoWeek(moment().subtract(1,'w').week());
  var mondayDifference  = lastWeek.dayOfYear() - lastWeek.weekday() + 1;
  var sundayDifference  = mondayDifference - 1;

  var lastMonday        = moment().dayOfYear(mondayDifference);
  var lastSunday        = moment().dayOfYear(sundayDifference  );
```

Answer (score 1):

it can be this simple.

```
var today = new Date();
var sunday = new Date(this.today.getFullYear(), this.today.getMonth(), this.today.getDate() - this.today.getDay());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a multi-purpose function:

```
 function getThe(numOfWeeks, weekday, tense, fromDate) { 
 // for instance: var lastMonday = getThe(1,"Monday","before",new Date()) 
      var targetWeekday = -1;  
      var dateAdjustment = clone(fromDate);  
      var result = clone(fromDate);

      switch (weekday) {
        case "Monday": targetWeekday = 8; break;
        case "Tuesday": targetWeekday = 2; break;
        case "Wednesday": targetWeekday = 3; break;
        case "Thursday": targetWeekday = 4; break;
        case "Friday": targetWeekday = 5; break;
        case "Saturday": targetWeekday = 6; break;
        case "Sunday": targetWeekday = 7;
      }

      var adjustment = 7 * (numOfWeeks - 1);
      if (tense == "after") adjustment = -7 * numOfWeeks;

      dateAdjustment.setDate(fromDate.getDate() - targetWeekday);
      var weekday = dateAdjustment.getDay();

      result.setDate(fromDate.getDate() - weekday - adjustment);
      result.setHours(0,0,0,0);
      return result;
  }
```

You can find the "clone(obj)" function in the next post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/6751764

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a third party date library to deal with dates. For example:**

```
var startOfWeek = moment().startOf('week').toDate();
var endOfWeek   = moment().endOf('week').toDate();
```

**if you want to use JavaScript then use the below code**

```js
var curr = new Date; // get current date
      var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay()+1; // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
      var last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6
      var startDate = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
      startDate = ""+startDate.getFullYear()+"-"+ (startDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + startDate.getDate() 

      var endDate = new Date(curr.setDate(last));
      endDate = "" + (endDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + endDate.getDate() + "/" + endDate.getFullYear();
      
       alert(startDate+" ,   "+endDate)
```